# If the total resistance of the circuit is 5 Ω, determine the value of R3

Tags: resistors, parallel, series, circuits

[image]

So far I have answered question 1a and parts of b. This is my step by step process:

1a) P=IV

P = V/R x V
P = 20/10 x 20
P = 40 W

b) RT = 5, R1 = 10, R2 = 5; R3 = ?

let R3 = x

RT = 5+10+x
5+10+x = 5

Where do I go from here, is the answer a negative value?

Comment: The combination of R2 and R3 can be thought of as a single resistor in parallel with R1. How big should that resistor be to give a total resistance of 5 ohms? You need to use the formula for **parallel** resistors here.

Comment: RT = (10 * (x +5))/(10+ (x +5)).

Comment: But we still have the unknown if we add both R2+R3 together and then the parallel resistor formula would be 1/10+ 1/5+R3 unless I am missing another equation? the first that comes to mind is the product/sum equation for resistors

Comment: Rtotal = R1 || (R2 + R3), or 5 = 10 || (5 + R3), say 5 Ω is 10 Ω parallel to x Ω. What is x? Then, R3 = (x - 5) Ω.

Answer (score 2):

The series of R2 and R3 sums up. Let's call this theoretical combined resistor R23. The substitute R23 is then in parallel with R1, so you need the formula for parallel resistors

1/Rtotal = 1/R1 + 1/R23

and you solve that for R23. Next, undo the substitution for the series of R2 and R3.

Since still not clear as per the comment, here's a step by step solution:

> `1/Rtotal = 1/R1 + 1/R23`     - input given values 
>  `1/(5 Ω) = 1/(10 Ω) + 1/R23`  - isolate R23 
>  `1/(5 Ω) - 1/(10 Ω) = 1/R23`  - make fraction same divisor 
>  `2/(10 Ω) - 1/(10 Ω) = 1/R23` - calculate 
>  `1/(10 Ω) = 1/R23`            - 1/x 
>  `R23 = 10 Ω`                 
>  
>  `R23 = R2 + R3`   - input given values
>  `10 Ω = 5 Ω + R3` - isolate R3
>  `10 Ω - 5 Ω = R3` - calculate
>  `R3 = 5 Ω`

Comment: I keep on getting -5 and I don't believe this is correct, I had used the product/sum rule and defined it as 10*(x+5)/10+(x+5)=RT where RT is 5 and x is R3

Comment: @AckimNkole: I've updated the answer to include a step by step solution

Comment: Thank you so much, I've figured out where the issue was since RT was given you can do 1/5 and then from here on in it is just simplifiyng. This is a much simpler version than my previous attempts

Answer (score 0):

a) P = (E² / R1) = (20² / 10) = 40 W.

b) R1 being 10 Ω , the resistance in parallel should be 10 Ω for the combination to be 5 Ω.

Hence (R2 + R3) = 10 Ω

(5 + R3) = 10 Ω

R3 = 5 Ω.